# assembly on a raspberry pi - multiplying two large numbers is giving me a surprising result

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3

I'm just screwing around with assembly on my raspberry pi:

```
global _start

_start:         mov r0, #0x7fffffff
                mov r1, #0x7fffffff
                muls r2, r0, r1
```

I'd expected some strange result in r2, and the overflow bit in the CPSR set, instead I got:

```
r0             0x7fffffff       0x7fffffff
r1             0x7fffffff       0x7fffffff
r2             0x1      0x1
cpsr           0x10     0x10 (a 0 overflow bit)
```

This is so stupid-dumb simple that I'm ready to get a facefull of blowback, but I've stared at it a while and googled a bunch.  Can anyone tell me why the #1 in r2, and why squaring a huge number doesn't overflow?

Comment: Open your desktop calculator app, switch it into "programmer" mode, type in 7fffffff * 7fffffff, and look at the [bottom 32 bits of the result](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1361289882394.html). What do you see?

Comment: C Flag = unaffected
/* See "C flag" note */
V Flag = unaffected

Comment: from some arm docs

Comment: if S == 1 then N and Z are affected

Comment: Thanks all.  Appreciated.

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, how would one detect an overflow in a multiply operation in an ARM? I can't think of a way other than long multiply instructions and checking the high register for non-zero. Maybe I'm overlooking something easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x7FFFFFFF * 0x7FFFFFFF = 0x3FFFFFFF00000001

Since [`mul` returns the least-significant 32 bits of the result](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1361289882394.html), and the least-significant 32 bits of that result are 0x00000001, it should be little surprise that the result is 1.

As to why it doesn't set the overflow flag, well, the answer is because it doesn't. Historically, the early ARM implementations implemented [Booth's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm) in-place, hence the note that the C and V flag are corrupted prior to ARMv5 (because of the shifts and additions happening in the ALU) and the two operands having to be in different registers prior to ARMv6 (because otherwise the writeback of intermediate results to one operand would also corrupt the other and yield a nonsense result). The multiplier implementations may have improved since (other than the space-saving Cortex-M0 "small multiplier" option, iterative algorithms are long-dead), making the original restrictions moot, but the architectural behaviour remains.